# Dahon Boardwalk 6 conversion

Tags: cassette

I wish to convert the 6sp to an 8sp.

Which model Dahon has the best 8 speed wheel unit to change the existing 6s speed wheel?

Also, what 3 speed hub gear would fit with the 6sp/wheel unit?

Cheers.

Comment: I've done this, it was expensive, and involved a new wheel hub, rebuilding of wheel, cassette, rear mech, and shifter.  And frankly it wasn't worth doing in the end.    Instead go straight for a 7/8/11/14 speed internally geared hub that matches your OLD.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Dahon specific wheel to upgrade from 6 speeds to 8. Bicycle wheels (like practically all bicycle components) are very standardized.

What you need is any wheel with:

- The correct rim diameter
- Acceptable rim width for the tires you want to use
- Correct hub width/dropout spacing
- 8/9/10 speed freehub (slightly wider than those used for 7 speeds and below)

A difficulty I can foresee is that Dahon 6 speed bikes might use an older style 120 or 126mm wide hub rather than the now standard 130 or 135mm. An 8/9/10 speed hub that takes a cassette  will not be available in that width. Dropout spacing is very easy to measure with a ruler so you should check what you bike has.

Comment: Thanks. So how does that mean I won't be able to simply change the 6sp Freewheel Wheel to an 8sp Hub Gear Wheel? Is it the Dropout Distance?

Comment: @stewie60 Note I updated the warding of my answer -  you *might* have a narrower dropout spacing so check that before proceeding. There may possibly be internally geared hubs available in 120 or 126 width.also.

Comment: I think the Dahon uses an internal gear hub. According to [Sheldon Brown](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/nexus8.shtml) you could reduce a Shimano Nexus 8 to 126mm: “The Nexus 8-speed hubs have a overlocknut spacing ranging of 132 to 135 mm, as sold: see Shimano's overlocknut spacing chart. It is possible to reduce the spacing of the Nexus Rollerbrake/freewheeling models to as little as 126 mm by leaving off the Rollerbrake and using a narrower locknut.”

Comment: This is great info team, thankyou. One more Q: Can a 7sp Freewheel be attatched to this 6sp? (I have an Altus RD) Perhaps with a narrower chain? I MUST get at least 1 more gear!